# Renaming images in bulk from array using Gulp

Tags: javascript, image, optimization, gulp, rename

I want to resize and rename images in bulk using Gulp. I have a task that works by renaming files according to their dimensions, but I would like to use shorthand in the filenames like `-small` and `-large` and just use the numerical value for the process of resizing.

I've tried adding a few iterations of key:value pair array to the `.forEach` line...

`[small:100, large:1000].forEach(function (size)`
`[{small:100, large:1000}].forEach(function (size)`

...and then trying to target the key/value in the image `imageResize` line, where "k" would be the key. This isn't working for me and I haven't been successful in tracking this part down on my own so far.

```
.pipe(rename(function (path) { path.basename = `${path.basename}-${size[k]}px`; }))
```

Here is the current task, which gets the job done. It resizes the image based on `size`, and then appends `size` to the filename as a string.

```
// Optimize Images
gulp.task("images", function (done) {
  [100, 1000].forEach(function (size) {
    return gulp.src(imagesSRC)
    .pipe(newer(imagesDestSite)) // get newer images
    .pipe(imageResize({ width: size })) // resize each according to array above
    .pipe(rename(function (path) { path.basename = `${path.basename}-${size}px`; })) // put size in filename
    .pipe(imagemin())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(imagesDest))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(imagesDestSite))
  });
  done();
});
```

The output from the task currently looks like this:

`image1-100px.jpg
image1-1000px.jpg
image2-100px.jpg
image2-1000px.jpg`

Which works, but I would prefer the output to be this:

`image1-small.jpg
image1-large.jpg
image2-small.jpg
image2-large.jpg`

Any pointers would be much appreciated, and thanks in advance!

Comment: In the body of your `rename` function just set a variable: `if  (size === 1000) var foo = "large"` and use `foo` in the next line where you set `path.basename`.  Let me know if that isn't clear. `path.basename = \`${path.basename}-${foo}\`;`

Comment: Facepalm - hadn't even occurred to me to use an if/else statement. I keep forgetting Gulp is just JavaScript. Your suggestion worked great, thank you!